# Regex to match end of the word

Tags: java, android, regex

I need very simple regex that will remove ending 's' in the word

```
String s = "javas";
s = s.replace("s$", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

surprisingly this does not work. ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `string.replaceAll` function where `replace` won't accept a regex as an argument.

```
s = s.replaceAll("s$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use substring to remove the last character.

```
if(fieldName.endsWith("s"))
{
  fieldName = fieldName.substring(0,fieldName.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the word isn't the last one in the string, use word boundary:

```
s = s.replaceAll("s\b", "");
```